# DocC index shows a blank page when using MAMP

Tags: xcode, mamp, docc

I am trying to perform a POC for the company I work to see the potential value we can get by using DocC in our project.

Before my development, I saw the 4 videos related to DocC from WWDC 2021, visit [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers) and read some pages and blogs to gather some information and thoughts.

For my development, I started using MAMP on my dev machine before pushing the work to the server.

So far, I think I have done all the necessary steps to host the doccarchive on the website. However, I wonder if I have missed something as my index.html looks blank.

The code I used is:

**index.html** (main)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DocC POC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <button onclick="location.href = 'documentation/index.html';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Read data framwework documentation</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Enable custom routing.
RewriteEngine On
# Route documentation and tutorial pages.
RewriteRule ^(documentation|tutorials)\/.*$ Data.doccarchive/index.html [L]
# Route files and data for the documentation archive.
#
# If the file path doesn't exist in the website's root ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ... route the request to that file path with the documentation archive.
RewriteRule .* Data.doccarchive/$0 [L]
```

**File structure**

[image]

**Picture prooving that the doccarchive is not empty**

[image]

**Picture of blank page**

[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: Having the same issue too, did you solve it?

Comment: @Terry I am afraid I haven't ...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to try it on github pages and was showing blank until I used the path `{base path}/documentation/{project name}`
so in your case try to replace `index.html` with your project name